# Problem with wordpress version 3.8

Tags: plugins, errors

[image]

Hi I have just updated wp version 3.8 and whenever I install plugins , in most of the cases the plugins shows an error or warning that certain variable in the plugin is not defined.
In some of the cases I have gone to the code and fixed by declaring the variable myself
This is just one case but if I use the same plugin with version 3.7 everything seems to run fine and not just with one plugin but many other plugins as well
I want to know what has changed that is causing the problem.
I just used php function 'empty($variable)' to remove this error

Comment: what variables are undefined?  Can we see examples?

Answer (score 2):

Deactivate flash album gallery plugin then try again may be this plugin version not match to wordpress latest version. This plugin may not be compatible with wordpress 3.8, you must wait for the new release.

Nonetheless, they are just notices you can simply hide these notices by going `wp-config.php` and toggle `WP_DEBUG` to `false`.

Comment: Not only this plugin but this happened with many other plugins as well, that's why I reverted back to version 3.7

Comment: @AkashArora see my edit!

Comment: My primary concern is why this notice is not shown in version 3.7 but in 3.8, I know notices don't affect the flow

Comment: I already said this is plugin issue. you can ask to plugin author which plugin create a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you try to deactivated all plugin and change your theme? **My solution for you is change your theme.**

I guess if you use default theme, it won't getting error. Default version of WordPress never get bug like this. If it is not getting error, you can activated your plugin one by one.
You will see, a theme or plugin that cause a error.

**Plugin and Theme**, there are only 2 things that make WordPress error. Because, they come from 3rd party, and sometimes plugin and theme out there *are not compatible* with new version of WordPress.